# Trying to modify list output using Python 3

Tags: python, list

Im trying to write a program to take in a file input, read the file and save the contents to a list. Then it counts each word and prints the top 'n' number of words which in my example is 10.

When I print the final value it prints

> ('the', 31) ('of', 24) ('to', 16) ('we', 16) ('and', 13) ('a', 12) ('our', 10) ('that', 8)('not', 7) ('in', 7)

Im trying to achieve the output of

> { the : 31 , of : 24, to : 16 , and : 13, a : 12 , our : 10 , that : 8, not : 7, in : 7}

Currently my code is:

```
mostFrequent = [] #list to hold the contents
fileName = input("Enter a file name: ")
with open(fileName, "r") as i: #while file is open read each line and add it to the list
  for line in i:
    mostFrequent.extend(line.split())

wordCounter = Counter(mostFrequent) #counts each word in the list
topMostFrequent = wordCounter.most_common(10) #gets top 10 most common words
print(*topMostFrequent, sep='\n') #printing list without [] and putting each value on new line
```

I tried converting the list to a dictionary since it seems the dictionary would produce the output I wanted but I couldn't get it to work, any help would be excellent!

Comment: How exactly did you try? It’s as simple as `dict(topMostFrequent)`.

Comment: `dict(wordCounter.most_common(10))` should do the trick

Comment: I tried to do ```dict(topMostFrequent)``` but it printed each word and their count in the file. I also figured it out, instead of just printing my list, I'm now iterating through and printing each key followed by a ```':'``` then the value and it prints what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

1. 

```
dict(topMostFrequent)
```

2. 

```
topMostFrequent = [('the', 31), ('of', 24), ('to', 16), ('we', 16), ('and', 13), ('a', 12), ('our', 10) ,('that', 8),('not', 7), ('in', 7)]
topMostFrequent = {i[0]:i[1] for i in topMostFrequent }
topMostFrequent
```

3. 

```
topMostFrequent = [('the', 31), ('of', 24), ('to', 16), ('we', 16), ('and', 13), ('a', 12), ('our', 10) ,('that', 8),('not', 7), ('in', 7)]
topMostFrequent = dict(map(lambda x: [x[0],x[1]], topMostFrequent))
# or dict(map(lambda x: x, topMostFrequent))
topMostFrequent
```

Output:

```
{'the': 31,
 'of': 24,
 'to': 16,
 'we': 16,
 'and': 13,
 'a': 12,
 'our': 10,
 'that': 8,
 'not': 7,
 'in': 7}
```

Comment: That’s a complicated way of doing `dict(topMostFrequent)`.

Comment: @deceze I know, I just want to show some ways. ;)